# Add Class After 4th Post

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I need to add a "div" after the 4th post. I am showing 8 posts on the page and the code i am using above shows the div after the 4th and 8th... o just need the 4th to show not every 4th, just after the first 4th.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : $count = 0; ?>
  <?php query_posts("showposts=8&post_type=vender_list&orderby=rand");?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> <?php echo eh_postImage(240,240,1); ?>
     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <?php the_content_rss('', FALSE, '', 60); ?>
    </article>
<?php if ($count % 4 == 3) { ?>
<div class="vender_hr"></div>
<?php } ?>
   <?php $count++;  ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: `showposts` is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check `$wp_query->current_post` instead of using that `mod` operator.

```
if ($wp_query->current_post === 4) { ?>
    <div class="vender_hr"></div>
<?php }
```

But don't use `query_posts`. Create a new `WP_Query` object. What you are doing is kind-of weird. You are checking to see if there are posts, then clobbering the main query which invalidates the `have_posts` check you just did, and then Looping though the post set. That really should look something more like this:

```
$qry = new WP_Query("posts_per_page=8&post_type=post&orderby=rand");
if ($qry->have_posts()) { 
  while ($qry->have_posts()) {
    $qry->the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> <?php echo eh_postImage(240,240,1); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content_rss('', FALSE, '', 60); ?>
    </article><?php 
    if ($qry->current_post === 4) { ?>
      <div class="vender_hr"></div><?php 
    } 
  }
}
```

Also, `the_content_rss` has been deprecated since WpordPress 2.9. If you had [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) as you should have while you are working, you'd see the notice.

Comment: What should i be using other than the_content_rss. I googled and hit up WordPress and didnt find much.

Comment: Just check the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content_rss#Replace_with

Comment: Seems to be placing <div class="vender_hr"></div> after the 5th post not the 4th.

Comment: Just decrement the number. `$wp_query->current_post` counts from 0 so 4 will put it after the fifth post, which is what I thought you wanted. I must have misread or confused myself (as happens a lot).